# Script time zone issue

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

The script running in the wrong time zone should be GMT+2

I tried changing the spreadsheet settings and project properties.

```
    function onEdit(e) {
   var TIME_ZONE = "GMT+2"; 
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),"Africa/Johannesburg", 'hh:mm:ss');

  //if column A has been edited, set date in same row in column B
  if (e.range.getColumn() == 1) {
    var row = e.range.getRow();
    e.source.getSheetByName('validated').getRange(row, 2).setValue(date);
  }
}
```

Even tried this :

```
var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), TIME_ZONE, 'hh:mm:ss');
```

Need the time stamp to set to the current time on Edit.

Comment: Please, update your question with this test log:
`function getTZ() {
  var scriptTZ = Session.getScriptTimeZone();
  Logger.log(scriptTZ);
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your format to `hh:mm:ss a`, adding `a` will set format to desired AM/PM range. See the `SimpleDateFormat` class [specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) on Oracle for more details on how to correctly format dates with `Utilities.formatDate()` method.
If there is still a problem, please, refer to my earlier comment.

Comment: Thanks, was looking over that document and tried all other methods but this. :)

Comment: NP! It's usually the overlooked one :)